# Auto reloading a div tag in jquery is not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a simple page that contains javascript code that refresh a div tag every 2 seconds, The code is working in firefox and safari, but is not working in chrome.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
        $('#reload').load('page.php');
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

And the `page.php` page contains the text `<?php echo "This is a test for auto reload"; ?>`.

So what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools in Chrome (press F12) to look at the network traffic? This would be a good place to start, as it will tell you if the AJAX request is ever being sent to the server, and if so what the response is. You need to look under the Network tab.

Comment: Did you check browser console for errors??

Comment: I checked your script and it is working in chrome. Log the ajax request status code to check for problem `$('#reload').load('page.php', function(response, status, xhr){
 console.log(xhr.status);
});`

Comment: I tested ur code. It's work fine. check ur chrome version

Comment: Is the ajax log enabled in chrome console? You can enable log by right clicking in chrome console.

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel that what I see when I open The network Tab

http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvBo2.png

Comment: See that what appears to me when I open the network tab in inspect element. http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvBo2.png

Comment: Is there anything in the Console?

Comment: Try to append a random url parameter to your call to avoid cache issues perhaps?